# How to alternate images and show div content on click?

Tags: javascript, html

What I am looking to achieve is that when an image is clicked, the content is shown and the image changes to another image, and when this is clicked again the image reverts back and the content becomes hidden

Currently I have this in script tags

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function setVis(id, vis) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = vis;
}
function swapImage() {
switch (imageNo) {
 case 1:
   image.src = "images/img.png"
   imageNo = 2
   return(false);
case 2:
   image.src = "images/img1.png"
   imageNo = 1
   return(false);
}
}
</script>
```

and this in the main html page

```
<h4><a href="#" onclick="setVis('content','inline');return false;"><img id="image" name="image" src="images/img.png" width="10" height="10" border="0" onclick="swapImage();"/></a> Content</h4>
```

This doesn't work it shows the content but it won't hide it again, and the images do not change.

I would appreciate any help that can be offered thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the toggle for you.

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var imageNo = 2;
function swapImage() {
image = document.getElementById('image')
switch (imageNo) {
 case 1:
   image.src = "images/img.png"
   imageNo = 2
   document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'none'
   return(false);
case 2:
   image.src = "images/img1.png"
   imageNo = 1
    document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block'
    return(false);
}
}
</script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <h4><a href="#"><img id="image" name="image" src="images/img.png" border="0" onclick="swapImage();"/></a></h4>
  <div id="content" style="display:none">This content toggles</span>
 </body>
```

Comment: Actually you can remove the anchor tag if you don't require the cursor to be a pointer. If you want you can use css to make cursor as pointer when you hover over the image. Don't forget to choose this as an answer :)

Comment: @Tom: Please choose this as the answer since it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

i think it may be easier (imho because i hate working in javascript) to use jquery, using jquery you can have a look at the toggle function which gives you this functionality very easy. I believe it has less of a learning curve than neat javascript. If you need any help let me know.

[Jquery Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Could you point me to any tutorials on jquery as I have never used it before?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp this is generally good, its a case of finding the DOM element and adding a function(very basic summary) alot easier than javascript imho

Answer (score 0):

Here is similar solution like dev_musings but with a few less lines of code (for more about [Alternate image with javascript onclick](http://interestingwebs.blogspot.com/2012/09/change-image-onclick-with-javascript.html) follow the link):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">    
    function swapImage() {
        var image = document.getElementById('image');
        if (image.src == "images/img.png")  
        {
                image.src = "images/img1.png";  
                document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'none';              
        }
        else
        {
                image.src = "images/img.png";
                document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';
        }
        return(false);
    }
</script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <h4><a href="#"><img id="image" name="image" src="images/img.png" border="0" onclick="swapImage();"/></a></h4>
  <div id="content" style="display:none">This content toggles</span>
 </body>
```